# How does Colonel Dugan have the police and school on his side?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-next-karate-kid

In *The Next Karate Kid*, how does Colonel Dugan (Michael Ironside) have the police and school on his side?

Answer (score 1):

Likely because he leads a JROTC-style program called the Alpha Elite at Julie's school and this gives the school respect for him as well as the police since it’s likely affiliated with the military as well.

It is likely a random plot ploy but think of people you know who command ROTC programs in high school and how the people in charge are usually the military (which works and advises with law enforcement if it ever has to do with higher crimes requiring military expertise - more relevant today than back when the next Karate Kid was introduced...)